# ParseUser saveInBackground weird behaviour

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

For my Android application, I am using a Parse.com backend. I am trying to update information for a parse user, but the saveInBackground() method is acting strange to me.

When I have this code:

```
     HomeActivity.currentUser.put("dealNotifications",deals.isChecked());
         HomeActivity.currentUser.put("itemSuggestions",items.isChecked());
         HomeActivity.currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

The user, and the two fields "dealNotifications" and "itemSuggestions" are updated, but all other custom properties are deleted from the Parse browser.

On the other hand, when I have this code:

```
     HomeActivity.currentUser.put("dealNotifications",deals.isChecked());
         HomeActivity.currentUser.put("itemSuggestions",items.isChecked());
     HomeActivity.currentUser.put("favourites",HomeActivity.favourites);
         HomeActivity.currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

The Parse user is not updated at all.

I have no idea why this is happening. From my understanding, the saveInBackground() method should not modify fields that have not been changed, so the first behaviour is very odd. I also have no idea why adding another "put" causes the saveInBackground() method to do nothing.

Anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: Just an advice: when talking about a third party library, you should explain that clearly at the beginning. Not everybody knows what a "parse user" is.

Comment: Just wonder why you dont use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("YOUR_KEY", value);` Also, you can use the callback function inside your saveInBackground() method, so you can check if the user is updated successfully.

Comment: @ztan - `HomeActivity.currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` I tried replacing the code with `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` functions exactly the same.

Comment: @moneymango, you should do it with `ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` because this is the class method from ParseUser. It will work more appropriately. In addition, you should try putting a saveCallBack function inside your saveInBackground(), ex: `new SaveCallback() {
              public void done(ParseException e) {
                     if (e == null) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "SAVE SUCCESSFUL");   

                     } else {
                         Log.d(TAG, "SAVE FAILED " + e.getCause());   
                     }
                   }
                 });`

Comment: @ztan - As I said in the previous comment, I used `ParseUser.currentUser()` and it does not affect how the code functions. Also, the SaveCallBack returns no ParseException.